No longer able to view Review History for Save without review or Skip in Staging Ground
If I go to Save without review (editing a post without review) or Skip under review history, I used to be able to see activity from everyone. But now, I cannot see any activity whatsoever, even if I enable Show only my reviews even though I have most certainly edited posts without review, and was able to see them before.

I can still see activity for all other action types (such as Vote as off-topic) just fine.

We had an issue with how data was brought into that page, we've pushed a fix for it and the filters should now work as expected.
Let us know if there's any more issues! Thanks for reporting, appreciate the help.

Before the issue, "Skip" and "Edited without Review' wasn't part of "All Review Actions" but now it is. Is this intended? To be honest, I liked the old way more because I'm typically not that interested in skips but it was available when I wanted to check something.

@dan1st That might be intentional, but not showing Skip under All Review Actions, or at least having an option to filter them, might make a good [meta-tag:feature-request].

@CPlus Skip was an option for the filter the whole time. I want to know whether the changes to "All Review Actions" were intentional.

@dan1st correct, the reason they didn't show up in the "All Review Actions" is the same reason that was hiding them from the filters.
I agree with CPlus, excluding them from the main view would make a good feature-request!
